# How to obtain the Rows and Columns position (Highlighted by mouse event) in Pyqt5 table widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing python GUI using pyqt5 table widget. How Can I obtain the rows and columns position of a selected region? Actually, In the default PyQt5 table widget, the selected region is highlighted with blue color. How can I get this blue rows and columns coordinate ? Thank you

Comment: `QTableWidget::selectedItems()`  
Returns a list of all selected items.

This function returns a list of pointers to the contents of the selected cells. Use the `selectedIndexes()` function to retrieve the complete selection including empty cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several methods to obtain the rows and columns:

- Use the `selectedIndexes()` method.

```py
for ix in tablewidget.selectedIndexes():
    print(ix.row(), ix.column())
```

- Use the selectedItems() method, unlike the previous method this does not return the empty items.

```py
for it in tablewidget.selectedItems():
    print(it.row(), it.column())
```

If you want to obtain the rows and columns at the time of selection you must use the selectionChanged signal of the selectionModel associated with the QTableWidget. Unlike the previous methods, this also returns the deselected items.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(6, 6)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
            self.on_selectionChanged
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QItemSelection, QtCore.QItemSelection)
    def on_selectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        print("=====Selected=====")
        for ix in selected.indexes():
            print(ix.row(), ix.column())
        print("=====Deselected=====")
        for ix in deselected.indexes():
            print(ix.row(), ix.column())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```